# AWS Parameter Store getting multiple parameters is way slower than getting one at a time?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have been debugging this for a while and i can't seem to figure out why and find any logic in this case.

I am storing some parameters in Simple Systems Management, parameters such as jirahost, jirapassword, jirausername and such!

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient = (AWSSimpleSystemsManagement)((AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder)((AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder) AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard()).withRegion("us-east-1")).build();
GetParametersRequest paramRequest = new GetParametersRequest();
paramRequest.withNames(jiraHost, jiraUsername, jiraPassword, jiraIssueType, jiraProjectKey).setWithDecryption(true);
GetParametersResult paramResult = ssmClient.getParameters(paramRequest);
```

this is the code im using for receiving multiple parameters from the parameter store.

I am then using google guavas stopWatch to measure the time and it takes over 7 seconds to receive them all!

Then i tried calling just a single parameter:

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement simpleSystemsManagementClient = (AWSSimpleSystemsManagement)((AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder)((AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder) AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard()).withRegion("us-east-1")).build();
GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = new GetParameterRequest();
parameterRequest.withName(parameterKey).setWithDecryption(true);
GetParameterResult parameterResult = simpleSystemsManagementClient.getParameter(parameterRequest);
```

Using stopwatch again, this takes less than 300ms!?

Can you see something i can't? The easy way out would be to call the single parameter method multiple times but, i really want to figure out what is going on.

Hope you can help me

Comment: Did you actually make a benchmark, or are these just results of single execution? How many times in a row did you call those snippets before you concluded it's slower? Are you sure you don't race with something else and receive shared results? JVM is not easy enough a platform to be able to be satisfied with "simple" measures.

Comment: Also, what's with all the casting? All those methods return exactly what you're casting to, isn't your code just yellow from all the warnings of useless casts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply amazon aws warm up time. everytime i updated my lambda, first time calling the function it was this slow.

Afterwards it's as fast as always.

Answer (score 1):

You can request all parameters by path rather than naming them individually.

Here is an example I used in PHP:

```
$result = $ssm_client->GetParametersByPath(['Path' => '/inventory-app/']);
```

This returns all parameters under that *path*. So, try putting your parameters in a hierarchy and grabbing them all this way.